# Create shell script for server install

Tags: linux, centos

I've built my Centos server several times, and am still learning.

I've used tutorials, books, and forums to come up with what I think is correct.

I document all the steps in a word document, and then copy a line from the word document, and past it into the shell.

Am I able to create some sort of batch file (shell script, right?) to automate the process?  I am not talking about the initial Centos install, but adding packages, etc.  If the answer is "yes", I have a couple of specific questions:

1. How am I able to have the shell script edit a file (for instance, add "max_input_vars=10000" to php.ini)?
2. How do I use the shell script to importing and checking a RPM key work.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Build a server to your tastes, then reverse-engineer into a [POSIX shell script](http://devstructure.com/blueprint/#sh) using [**Blueprint**](http://devstructure.com/blueprint/). ;)

Anything beyond that, and you need to explore [configuration management frameworks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_open-source_configuration_management_software): Puppet, Chef, Saltstack, Ansible, etc.

Comment: Thanks ewwhite.  Sounds like a great idea.  Sounds like you recommend using Blueprint over the other configuration management frameworks, correct?  Am I able to show someone the outputted POSIX shell script (or some other outputted document) and have them critique my configuration?

Comment: I recommend proper configuration management, actually... but [Blueprint](http://devstructure.com/blueprint/) is a convenient way to obtain a server's configuration. And yes, you can preview the script.